Do 1000s of transactions at once
My idea is to create a service that gets the CSV of the user's list and sends SOL to them.
I want to send multiple (1000+) users at once. I saw that address per transaction is limited, how can I overcome this challenge and send funds to the users?

It's definitely possible, you just need to send many transactions.
Check out the solana-tokens for doing large distributions from CSV files: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/tree/master/tokens
